# How to select a local file for a file upload with python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation, chrome-web-driver

I have been writing the script to fill a form using Selenium with Python. I would like to attach an image file to it. So when I reach the button to upload the file and click it, I no longer can use Selenium to find the element.

I need to figure out how to enter the path to the image file, select it and upload it.

Please look at the image below to get a clear picture of what I am trying to do and let me know the solution.

[image]

Comment: You need to use AutoIT with selenium refer this https://www.guru99.com/use-autoit-selenium.html

Answer (score 2):

You can even try directly with `send_keys` function on `Browse` button that us used to select file. It doesn't involves any windows popup handling.

Example:

```
import os


driver.find_element_by_id("#button_id").send_keys(os.getcwd() + "/image.png")
```